# Is there a limited supply of Titanite?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Is there a limited supply of Titanite in Dark Souls 2? I know that in the first game, you could find merchants that never ran out of Titanite Shards but the only merchants I've found so far have a limited supply.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is not. A lot of the 'unlimited' supplies get unlocked later in the game. (For example there is a merchant that sells unlimited Large Shards and another that sells boltstones. I just don't know where the regular titanite one is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an unlimited supply of all forms of Titanite.

All Titanite up to Chunks are sold in unlimited supply by the NPC Stone Trader Chloanne.

Chloanne is found in Harvest Valley, until you talk to her so much she runs out of new things to say, in which case she’ll go to Majula. You can pretend it’s your fault.

Get unlimited Titanite Shard by clearing Iron Keep, unlimited Large Titanite Shard by clearing Drangleic Castle, and unlimited Titanite Chunks by clearing the Undead Crypt. When you get through the final boss, Titanite becomes infinite.

The only one that is left is Titanite Slab, which can be farmed off of the stone soldier in Drangelic Castle.

Although not part of the regular titanite upgrade path, Twinkling Titanite can be farmed off of the Archdrakes in Shrine of Amana. Alternatively they can be Acetic farmed in Dragon Aerie(5x?) and the Giant Memories(2x).

Comment: What about `Twinkling Titanite`

Comment: I had assumed the question was about the regular Titanite upgrade path, and answered as such. I have updated my answer to include twinkling titanite.